# Keeping the main name of column using dcast

Tags: r, dcast

I have rows with the same name and I want to convert them into columns keeping the main name of column and add the 1 or 2 etc. according to how many columns exist.

I use this to make it:

```
setDT(df)[, N:= 1:.N, maincol]
df <- dcast(df, url~N, value.var=c("stock"))
```

what I will expect is to have names like stock_1, stock_2 etc. However every column has only the number 1,2 etc. How can I modify it?

Comment: You can try `dcast(df, url~paste0("stock_", N), value.var = "stock")`

Comment: @akrun many thanks that it the answer!

Comment: @akrun if I have more than 2 columns I use this but it makes the 2 different names as one col name `dcast(df, url~paste0("stock_", "day_", N), value.var = c("stock", "day"))`

Comment: If there are more than 1 value.var columns, just do `dcast(df, url~  N, value.var = c( "stock", "day"))`